# Prove materiality uniform continuity condition.

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

I have a mapping $f:(X,\rho_x) \mapsto (Y,\rho_y)$, and we know, that $f$ - uniformly continuous mapping.

> $\forall A \subset X, A $ - precompact set $ \Rightarrow $ $f(A)$ - precompact set.
>
> Prove materiality uniform continuity condition.

Okey, but I don't how I need prove.

I know:

> Precompact set $A$ in a metric space is set, if its closure is compact in $X$.

But I don't understand why we must have a uniformly continuous mapping. Is this connected for proof of precompact set? How can I prove this statement?

Answer (score 0):

f(x)=1/x from the open interval (0, 1) is continuous, but non uniformly continuous, (0,1) is precompact, yet its image under f(x) is not.